# ActiveScaffold sort column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, activescaffold

I'm trying to add sorting to my activscaffold. Example code is:

```
active_scaffold :user do |config|
config.columns = [:id, :name, :rating]
config.list.per_page = 25
config.columns[:rating].sort = true
```

But when i check column 'RATING' isn't sortable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

list.sorting = {:rating => 'ASC'}

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your controller

```
def custom_finder_options
  {reorder: 'rating ASC'}
end
```